# Update no actualiza tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, update

Buenas al ejecutar mi codigo no logro modificar valor en base de datos.

**Modifica.php**

```
include ("conexion.php");

$usuario="jose";

$linku= $_POST["linkm"];

$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );




if($hola=mysqli_query("UPDATE link SET acceso=$linku WHERE usuario=$usuario")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $linku);
echo "modificacion ok";}
else
echo "no se pudo";
```

> siempre sale por el "no se pudo". Agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: siempre sale por el "no se pudo". Agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente tu código debería quedar así:

```
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');

$usuario="jose";
$linku= $_POST["linkm"];
$query=mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE link SET acceso='$linku' WHERE usuario='$usuario'");

if($query){
    echo "actualizado";
}else{
    echo "no actualizado";
}
```

**¿QUÉ HICE?**

1. Puedes en la instancia de `mysqli` pasar también el nombre de la base de datos, por lo cual no necesitas una función para conectarte y otra para seleccionar la base de datos
2. la variable `$query` almacenará la consulta, donde: primero paso la variable de la `$conexion` y posterior la query; nota como las variables las puse entre comillas simples
3. Por fuera mediante un simple condicional evalue si la variable `$query` se ejecuto o no, recordemos que posee un valor booleano por lo que basta con hacer `if(var)` para que con ello chequemos si se ejecuto o no

Con lo anterior tu código ya debe ser funcional

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Considerando que estas trabajando con `mysqli` y que estas recibiendo datos provenientes del usuario, lo ideal aqui es trabajar la consulta de forma preparada para prevenir *SQL INJECTION*, por lo cual tu consulta debería quedar así

```
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');
$linku= $_POST["linkm"];
$usuario="jose";

$query= $conexion->prepare("UPDATE link SET acceso= ? WHERE usuario= ?");
$query->bind_param('ss', $linku, $usuario);
$query->execute();
if($query){
    echo "actualizado";
}else{
    echo "no actualizado";
}
```

**LO QUE HICE**

1. Sustituir el llamado directo de las variables en la query, con los marcadores de posición `?`